# telegraf json serializer converts float to int when decimal part is 0 e.g. 1.0

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

In Telegraf, due to json specifications, the float field is truncated

telegraf.conf

```
[[inputs.execd]]
  command = ["/Users/test/tick/count_float.sh"]
[[outputs.file]]
  ## Files to write to, "stdout" is a specially handled file.
  files = [ "/tmp/metrics.out"]
  data_format = "json"
```

/Users/test/tick/count_float.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for counter in 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 1.0 2.0
do
    echo "counter_bash count=${counter}"
    sleep 10
done
```

Expected behavior

```
{"fields":{"count":0.0},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732609}
{"fields":{"count":0.1},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732619}
{"fields":{"count":0.2},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732629}
{"fields":{"count":0.3},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732639}
{"fields":{"count":0.4},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732649}
{"fields":{"count":0.5},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732659}
{"fields":{"count":0.6},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732669}
{"fields":{"count":1.0},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732679}
{"fields":{"count":2.0},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732689}
```

Actual behavior

```
{"fields":{"count":0},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732609}
{"fields":{"count":0.1},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732619}
{"fields":{"count":0.2},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732629}
{"fields":{"count":0.3},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732639}
{"fields":{"count":0.4},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732649}
{"fields":{"count":0.5},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732659}
{"fields":{"count":0.6},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732669}
{"fields":{"count":1},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732679}
{"fields":{"count":2},"name":"counter_bash","tags":{"host":"TEST"},"timestamp":1697732689}
```

During json marshaling, it drops float precision 1.0 to 1 and 2.0 to 2 in order to simplify. Practically its same value but the downstream system considers the fields as int which results in other unexpected behaviors. How can I solve this issue within telegraf itself?